# Maven Ear Plugin use missing class on plexus-utils

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

For project circumstances, I'm using older versions of Maven and Java, when I try to package the project, using maven ear plugin 2.7, uses plexus-utils version 1.1

The problem... It calls org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter, this class is not on plexus-utils version 1.1

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project PROJECT_NAME: Execution default-generate-application-xml of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:generate-application-xml failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:generate-application-xml: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
```

How it the way to force ear plugin to use other version of plexus-utils who include this class?

A part of pom file:

```
    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>PROJECT_NAME</finalName>
                    <displayName>PROJECT_NAME</displayName>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>PROJECT_NAME_01.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/PROJECT_NAME_01</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why using older versions of Maven or very old plugin versions (maven-ear-plugin 2.7 ca. 10 years old) ? Also it would be helpful to show the full error output ... Are you building on plain command line? Really using Maven 2???